# How can I create a smooth border emphasis when user clicks outside box?

Tags: jquery, css, border

I'm trying to have a box be emphasized when the user clicks outside of it (it's an error box).

I have been trying animations with jquery and then also simply css transitions, but they're not getting the smooth result I want. I just want a simple emphasis for the user to focus back on the alert. It's like any Windows or Apple alert where you click somewhere beside the alert and it makes a sound and also emphasizes the box.

I tried `transition:border linear 0.2s;` and then creating a border with jquery once the user clicks outside.

```js
popup = $("#popup");

$(window).on("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != "popup") {
    popup.css("border", "red solid 2px");
    setTimeout(function() {
      popup.css("border", "none");
    }, 250);
  }
})
```

```css
#popup {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border: white 1px solid;
  transition: border linear 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">Example.</div>
```

If anyone has a smooth solution that provides a soft emphasis or has links toward where I could find a way, that would be much appreciated. As always, thanks for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of border, I suggest outline.

```js
popup = $("#popup");

$(window).on("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id != "popup") {
    popup.css("outline-width", "10px");
    setTimeout(function() {
      popup.css("outline-width", "inherit");
    }, 250);
  }
})
```

```css
#popup {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  outline: solid 0px red;
  transition: outline 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">Example.</div>
```